# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS WordPress Multisite + Nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, multisite

I had three WordPress Installations `/basketball` `/football` and `/kitesurfen` each was defined in `nginx.conf` file with separate directories.

removed all configurations and installed a multisite on `/` path.

when I create new site with one of the previous paths e.g `/basketball` `/football` or `/kitesurfen` I can not access the dashboard. I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and different error based on browser.

If I create a site with any other path e.g `/test` `/volleyball` or `/swimming` it works fine.

Need help to fix this. I am not sure if its a WordPress (PHP) error or Nginx configurations error.

Nginx Conf

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /$2 break;
}

location / {
    root /var/www/html/multinetworks/networktheme;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    rewrite ^/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ /$1wp-admin/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ /$2 break;
    rewrite ^/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ /$2 break;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off; access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
    }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you reset your browser since making the changes?

Comment: yes, I cleared browser cache, tested in `incognito & private` window, tested on other systems and browsers.

Comment: @RichardSmith now i added a script to `die` the page once `wp-admin` is called. when i open `/test/wp-admin/` the page dies, but when i open `/basketball/wp-content` page does not die and keep reloading.